# How to compile Raspberry Pi on macOS Big Sur? Is there an OSX arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc toolchain somewhere?

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a pre-packaged arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc toolchain for OSX. Can someone point me to one?

Comment: If you couldn't find this on the Internet, and given that most guides you'll find will be Linux-based, I'd highly recommend doing this on Linux. If you're confident using the command line, you can use Docker, otherwise you can spin up a VM or install Linux natively. I'm not saying it can't be done on OSX, but if you're just starting out it's best to follow the existing guides and practices.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this guide from Jeff Geerling. He does a lot of work on the Raspberry Pi and has setup kernel cross compiling on his macbook.

https://github.com/geerlingguy/raspberry-pi-pcie-devices/tree/master/extras/cross-compile

https://www.youtube.com/c/JeffGeerling/

Answer (score 1):

There is an ARM toolchain for macOS (scroll the page until you see *macOS*):

- https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads

Also available as a [homebrew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils):

```
brew install arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils
```

Another alternative for building on macOS is Docker with the experimental `buildx` extension with something similar to:

```bsh
# create a builder instance
docker buildx create --name my-pi-crosscompiler --platform linux/arm/v7 --bootstrap --use

# build from a Dockerfile in the current folder
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 --progress tty -t picompiler  --load .
```

A minimal `Dockerfile`:

```bsh
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS cross-compiler

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends g++ cmake libconfig++-dev zlib1g && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /root

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

> ❗️ *Warning: compilation will be (significantly) slower than on bare metal because of the emulation layer.*

Another example on using `docker buildx` [here](https://chrz.de/2020/02/14/raspberry-pi-cross-compilation-using-docker/).